# Making bottles of gold!

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, crafting

I asked a question on how many gold coins it would take to craft a golden bottle for a gift. How would I go about making the bottle? I have no proficiency in it, and about how much would it cost me to do so? We're playing 5e. I would like to make it the size of a standard wine bottle. I know I need to smelt around 350 gold coins to get the correct amount of metal for it, but what else would I need to do? What skills would I need to use? All of this preferably without magic, if possible. I know I could use the wish spell, or just use an alchemy spell of sorts to change a normal bottle into gold. I'd prefer to do it manually, and make the gift mean more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Page 128 of Xanathar's Guide to Everything covers the downtime activity of "Crafting an Item".

> A character who has the time, the money, and the needed tools can use downtime to craft armor, weapons, clothing, or other kinds of nonmagical gear.
>
> In addition to the appropriate tools for the item to be crafted, a character needs raw materials worth half of the item's selling cost. To determine how many workweeks it takes to create an item, divide its gold piece cost by 50. [...]
>
> A character needs to be proficient with the tools needed to craft an item and have access to the appropriate equipment. *(XGE, 128)*

Strictly speaking, the only way you could possibly craft a wine bottle out of golden coins is to have proficiency in Smith's tools, which you don't.

Thankfully, not all is lost, as Xanathar's Guide *also* includes the downtime activity "Training", which allows a character to gain a proficiency in a tool.

> Given enough free time and the services of an instructor, a character can learn a language or pick up proficiency with a tool.
>
> ***Resources.*** Receiving training in a language or tool typically takes at least ten workweeks, but this time is reduced by a number of workweeks equal to the character's Intelligence modifier. Training costs 25 gp per workweek. *(XGE, 134)*

So, if you absolutely insist on crafting it yourself, by hand, using no magic, you would have to do the following:

1. Spend 10 weeks and 250 gp (potentially less, depending on Int) training under a willing blacksmith. This will give you proficiency in Smith's tools.
2. Resolve any complications, should your DM choose to roll for them.
3. Determine with your DM what the appropriate "selling cost" of the golden bottle would be worth. Since it will be using 350 gold coins, for the sake of argument, we'll say it has a value of 500 gp when we include labor.
4. Find a blacksmith that will allow you to use (or rent) their forge, and then spend 10 weeks (value divided by 50) crafting it, given its value.
5. Resolve any complications, should your DM choose to roll for them.
6. Enjoy your golden bottle, hand forged by your character.

Now, personally, I think ten weeks for the crafting itself is rather silly, but according to the actual rules for this, that is what it would take. Your DM may rule otherwise (and, were I your DM, I would).

Comment: Rather than dividing the full cost of the item by 50 to get the time it takes to create, it makes more sense to do so for only the labour part of the cost. In other words, subtract the material cost of the item before dividing by 50. Using this example it would be: (500 Gp - 350 Gp) / 50 Gp/week = 3 weeks. Three weeks makes more sense than ten weeks to make a bottle of gold, doesn't it?

Answer (score -6):

Gold is exceptionally ductile and malleable.  A person with a good smithing skill could probably just hammer one out.

This question doesn't need a long detailed answer; it's a simple problem.  It doesn't need any rules either.  He's making a gift; all he really needs is for he GM to say he can do it, and then they can all say he did it.  He gives the gift, and everyone is happy.

But here you go anyway, in case too much is not enough.  Get enough gold to make a bottle of the size you want, of reasonable thickness.  He had previously figured out that 350 gp would make a bottle of gold with the same thickness as the glass bottle being copied.  Make a form for the inside shape of the bottle, out of (for example) a metal with a lower melting point than gold.  Hammer the gold around the form until you like the bottle.  Remove the form.  Voila!